# SQL group by a field and only return one joined row for each grouping

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group, postgres-9.6

Table `data`

```
+-----+----------------+--------+----------------+
| ID  |  Required_by   |  Name  |  Another_Field |
+-----+----------------+--------+----------------+
| 1   |  7 August      |  cat   |  X             |
| 2   |  7 August      |  cat   |  Y             |
| 3   |  10 August     |  cat   |  Z             |
| 4   |  11 August     |  dog   |  A             |
+-----+----------------+--------+----------------+
```

What I want to do is group by the name, then for each group choose one of the rows with the earliest required by date.

For this data set, I would like to end up with either rows 1 and 4, or rows 2 and 4.

Expected result:

```
+-----+----------------+--------+----------------+
| ID  |  Required_by   |  Name  |  Another_Field |
+-----+----------------+--------+----------------+
| 1   |  7 August      |  cat   |  X             |
| 4   |  11 August     |  dog   |  A             |
+-----+----------------+--------+----------------+
```

OR

```
+-----+----------------+--------+----------------+
| ID  |  Required_by   |  Name  |  Another_Field |
+-----+----------------+--------+----------------+
| 2   |  7 August      |  cat   |  Y             |
| 4   |  11 August     |  dog   |  A             |
+-----+----------------+--------+----------------+
```

I have something that returns 1,2 and 4 but I'm not sure how to only pick one from the first group to get the desired result. I'm joining the grouping with the `data` table so that I can get the `ID` and `another_field` back after the grouping.

```sql
SELECT d.id, d.name, d.required_by, d.another_field
FROM 
(
  SELECT min(required_by) as min_date, name
  FROM data
  GROUP BY name
) agg
INNER JOIN 
data d
on d.required_by = agg.min_date AND d.name = agg.name
```

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically solved using window functions:

```
select d.id, d.name, d.required_by, d.another_field
from (
  select id, name, required_by, another_field, 
         row_number() over (partition by name order by required_by) as rn
  from data
) d
where d.rn = 1;
```

In Postgres using `distinct on()` is typically faster:

```
select distinct on (name) *
from data
order by name, required_by
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b4f61fecd616465d335f61a9dc5bce67)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT [id]
      ,[date]
      ,[name]
  FROM [test].[dbo].[data]  
  WHERE date IN (SELECT min(date) FROM data GROUP BY name)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAslk.png)

Comment: That's invalid (standard) SQL to begin with. But even if the (invalid) square brackets are ignored, it returns a wrong result as the date needs to be compared _together_ with the name, not independently. If at all you would need to use `where (date, name) in (select min(date), name from ...)`

Comment: SELECT id
      ,required_by
      ,name
      ,another_field
  FROM data 
  WHERE required_by IN (SELECT min(required_by) FROM data GROUP BY name)

Comment: Well, the question is about Postgres, not MS SQL . But your query will return wrong results if the data is slightly different: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=56c16ad7d5306d65fedeaf2bda4bc576

Comment: [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=cb5d987c6b81a10e552fb188b4a1ef3a)

Comment: Well, your last link shows that your query isn't correct. The expected output should contain `cat` only once. Your query returns two rows for `cat`

Comment: it only gets 1 cat in MSSQL. i don't know just try

Comment: No, it doesn't: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6db24dace89a0c3fb7b409f9f06590c4